# FileHelpers error: The field: 'k__BackingField' has the type: XXX that is not a system type, so this field need a CustomConverter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, serialization, filehelpers

I need to read a CSV file with FileHelpers based on type, automatically generated by my MVC model. The model looks like this:

```
public partial class Merchant
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Category { get; set; }

    public virtual MerchantCategory MerchantCategory { get; set; }
}
```

The last field is obviously generated by a foreign key in database, referring to table `MerchantCategories`.

Then I attempt to create an instance of `FileHelperEngine` with this type:

```
var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Merchant>();
```

And get the following exception:

> The field: 'k__BackingField' has the type: MerchantCategory that is not a system type, so this field need a CustomConverter ( Please Check the docs for more Info).

Actually I don't need this field at all for my import, so I tried to ignore it in derived class:

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class MerchantForImport : Merchant {
    [FieldHidden]
    new public MerchantCategory MerchantCategory;
}

var engine = new FileHelperEngine<MerchantForImport>();
```

And still the same error. I don't need this field at all, I don't want to implement any `FieldConverter` for it, I never asked for this `k__BackingField` and it's nowhere to be found in my code!

I can't call `FileHelperEngine.Options.RemoveField()` because the exception is thrown by the constructor.

Where does that come from? How do I get rid of it?

Comment: I can't comment, so I'll add a note this way. @shamp00 made this comment in his answer: > It works best with public fields (a FileHelpers limitation which is not C# best practice) I've noticed this to be true. If I use "internal" to define the class and members, then if I use `FileHelperEngine.GetFileHeader()` the header will be presented wrong. As an example, if one of the fields is "Address", then the header will show: `<Address>k__BackingField` I had to change the class and member definitions to use public in order to stop that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a design perspective, I think you are going about it the wrong way. You are trying to use the `Merchant` class for two incompatible uses. Instead you should have two separate classes.

FileHelpers is a library for describing csv files so that you can import them easily. You should have a `MerchantFileSpec` for describing your file. It's really not a proper C# class - it may have: dummy fields to represent unused columns; lots of attributes `[FieldNullValue]`, `[FieldQuoted]`, `[FieldConverter]`; etc. It works best with public fields (a FileHelpers limitation which is not C# best practice), etc. It is a *convenience* syntax for describing the import file. It should **not** include any business logic or special constructors, or backing fields. Keep it as simple as possible.

Then you can have your MVC-generated `Merchant` class which is separate. Its purpose is to describe the merchant as required by the MVC framework, with foreign keys, ids, whatever.

Then you use a `FileHelperEngine<MerchantFileSpec>` to read the records into an array and map it to an enumerable of `Merchant` (via Linq or a library like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)).

Something like:

```
/// Your MVC-generated class. Add methods, getters, setters, whatever.
/// FileHelpers doesn't use this class.
class Merchant
{
  public long Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public Nullable<int> Category { get; set; }

  public virtual MerchantCategory MerchantCategory { get; set; }
}

/// This is the class FileHelpers will use
/// This class describes the CSV file only. Stick to whatever
/// syntax conventions are required by FileHelpers.
[DelimitedRecord(";")]
class ProductMerchantFileSpec
{
    [FieldQuoted(QuoteMode.OptionalForRead)]
    public long Id;
    [FieldQuoted(QuoteMode.OptionalForRead)]
    public string Name;
    [FieldQuoted(QuoteMode.OptionalForRead)]
    // Handle non-US formats such as , decimal points
    // convert from inches to centimetres? 
    // you get the idea...
    [FieldConverter(MyCustomizedCategoryConverter)] // you get the idea
    public int Category;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var engine = new FileHelperEngine<ProductMerchantFileSpec>();
        var productMerchantRecords = engine.ReadFile(filePath);
        var productMerchants = productMerchantRecords
            .Select(x => new Merchant() { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name, Category = x.Category });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I already took your approach. It's a pity I can't bind to auto-generated type as I will have to modify the code manually every time there are changes to the table in DB to ensure the schemas coincide. Well, that won't be everyday routine, so I think it's okay.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error specifically because my object (i.e. Merchant) was missing a column that existed in the source file.  I was able to work around the issue prior to realizing the missing column by adding a new property to my object class    **public string[] MyProperty { get; set; }**.   This work-around help me realize a column was missing.

i.e..

public partial class Merchant
{
    public long id { get; set; }
..
..
..
   public string[] MyProperty { get; set; } 
}